# MAX at compile time?

Tags: c, arrays, compilation, max, sizeof

```
static const char * a = "0,0,0,%d,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0";
static const char * b = "0,%d,0,0,0,0,0,0,%d,0,0,0";

void function(void)
{
  const uint16_t bufferSize = MAX(sizeof(a),sizeof(b));
  char bufferData[bufferSize+1];
}
```

*I now this code is not valid, but it's for the idea.*

The goal is to define an array just enough large to hold the greatest constant string between a and b.

- As sizeof is evaluate at compile time, all the informations are available to evaluate the size before run time. There is any known solution for this?
- If yes, how expand this to n string rather than two?

Comment: Note, that `sizeof(a) = sizeof(b) = sizeof(char*)`

Comment: You can use the regular conditional operator, and it will evaluate in the compile time on any decent compiler able to recognize constant expressions. See here: https://godbolt.org/g/dfWy7h

Comment: Something like `#define S1 "qwe"  #define S1 "asdf"  char bufferData[sizeof(S1) > sizeof(S2) ? sizeof(S1) : sizeof(S2)];`?

Comment: Ok thanks, I see my mistake. I already use the conditional operator for my MAX macro, sorry to not show it. So the compiler does not accept to store the MAXed value in a temporary const variable, but accept direct attribution of the size of the array from MAX macro. Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you're not locked on to the types of your strings, just that they are a constant string, you can have them as `char[]` types to make this work:

```
#define SIZE(Z) (sizeof(Z)/sizeof(char))
#define MAX(X,Y) SIZE(X) > SIZE(Y) ? SIZE(X) : SIZE(Y)

int main()
{
    char a[] = "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf";       // length: 24
    char b[] = "adsfasdfasdfasdfasdfa";          // length: 21

    char buffer[MAX(a, b) + 1];

    printf("buffer size: %d\n", MAX(a, b) + 1); // returns 25

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already use this MAX macro, sorry to not show that. The compiler don't accept to pass throw a const variable, as I do in my code example. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "don't accept to pass throw", but modifying them to include `const` doesn't affect it with my compiler. Also I realized I didn't see the second part of your question: you can't have recursive macros nor anything more complicated than an `if` block and expect it to be done in the preprocessor; you're stuck calling nested MAX's to figure out `n` array sizes to declare an array.